# Python list comprehension, unpacking and multiple operations

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, flatten

I want to unpack the tuples I create by doing the following so he the result is just one simple list. I can get the desired result in 2-3 lines but surely there is a oneliner list.comp?

```
>>> x = range(10)
>>> y = [(i,j**2) for i,j in zip(x,x)]
>>> y
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (6, 36), (7, 49), (8, 64), (9, 81)]
```

What I want is `result = [0,0,1,1,2,4,3,9.....]`

Doing

```
y = len(x)*[0]
y[::2] = x
y[1::2] = [i**2 for i in x]
```

Gives what I want but what if I need the more general case:

```
y = [(i, sqrt(i), i**3, some_operation_on_i, f(i), g(i)) for i in x]
```

Eg I should be able to get a straight list like result where I only specified one operation (square) to follow each i but now with an arbitrary number of operations following each i.

Comment: Really you want to unpack (flatten) a list-of-tuples into a flat list.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
result = [a for tup in y for a in tup]
```

Example:

```
>>> x = range(10)
>>> y = [(i,j**2) for i,j in zip(x,x)]
>>> [a for tup in y for a in tup]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81]
```

This will work fine for your more general case as well, or you could do it all in one step:

```
y = [a for i in x for a in (i, sqrt(i), i**3, some_operation_on_i, f(i), g(i))]
```

In case the nested list comprehensions look odd, here is how this would look as a normal `for` loop:

```
y = []
for i in x:
    for a in (i, sqrt(i), i**3, some_operation_on_i, f(i), g(i)):
        y.append(a)
```

Comment: The one-line solution is awesome. I fiddled around with that quite a while until this post showed me that I had the order of the nested for loops the wrong way around...

Answer (score 28):

Given

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> x = range(3)
>>> y = [(i, j**2) for i, j in zip(x, x)]
>>> y
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4)]
```

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```py
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(y))
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4]
```

To skip over the intermediary `y`:

```py
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((i, j**2) for i, j in zip(x, x)))
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Why not just `itertools.chain.from_iterable(y)`

Comment: @DevAggarwal: Good point, this has been available since Python 2.6.